# Hide boot messages

Tags: linux, debian, boot, init.d

I want to hide boot messages at startup in debian. I saw [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/258359/debian-boot-hide-all-messages) and it was so useful as it said i do this to `/etc/init.d/rcS`:

```
exec /etc/init.d/rc S >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and the result was what I want. but still there are some messages. How can I hide them?

```
starting portmap daemon ... Already running ..
starting NFS common utilities: statd.
starting enhanced syslogd: rsyslogd.
and ....
```

Comment: Why do you want this, if something ever breaks or fails on boot you wont know what it is that easy.

Comment: i just do not want the user see the messages ...

Comment: And why do you think this will bother the user?

Comment: @Lucas Kauffman: Most non-technical users are intimidated by seeing lots of status text scrolling by. Many desktop Linux distros have this information hidden behind a graphical logo and/or progress bar, but Debian doesn't. I can see why someone would want to hide that if they were deploying Debian-based desktops in their company.

Comment: Exactly. You have to see it from the end user's perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by installing and configuring [Plymouth](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth). Depending on your graphics card configuration, you might need some additional configuration as documented in the [Debian wiki entry for Plymouth](http://wiki.debian.org/plymouth). But before you make all of those changes, try the following commands and see if they work for you.

Start by installing the Plymouth package.

```
apt-get install plymouth
```

Then edit `/etc/default/grub` and modify the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` parameter to have the following values.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Finally, update the grub config files.

```
update-grub2
```

Now when you boot you will no longer see the diagnostic messages. The messages are supposed to be logged to /var/log/boot.log but it's broken in squeeze. This page claims to have a patch: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bug-678982-plymouth-boot-log-not-created-help-207993181.html

Plymouth comes with several boot themes. The default theme is called "text" which will display a blue progress bar at the bottom of the screen during boot. If you'd like to change the boot theme, run the following command with your desired theme name. The `-R` option is used to rebuild initrd which must be done when changing the theme.

```
plymouth-set-default-theme -R <theme>
```

To see a list of available themes, run the following command.

```
plymouth-set-default-theme --list
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing your colors -- you have the problem of changing every startup script.

the following changes the foreground color to black and the background to black:

```
echo -e "\033[30m\033[40m Hello World"
```

To get yourself back to readable, type 'reset'

so, I would try changing rcS to:

```
echo -e "\033[30m\033[40m" 
exec /etc/init.d/rc S
reset
```

That should change the cursor color, and then reset -- the gotcha is if you have an error and the startup script changes the font to yello or red.